# Right way to store a large set of similar information on website?

Tags: custom-post-types, posts, custom-taxonomy, database, table

I want to add a list of companies' information to my website and I want to display the list in a page. Then by clicking on each company, user can see more information about that company in its individual page.

What is the right approach for doing this? I researched about custom post types and custom fields. But they seem to be ***not right for me***. Do I have to build a post for each company? They are more than a hundred. Is there a more speedy way to do this?

P.S The companies has **identical fields**. Each company has a name, description, etc and also has **a few photos**.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is a good CPT plugin to make a list of companies in my website?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/378169/what-is-a-good-cpt-plugin-to-make-a-list-of-companies-in-my-website)

Comment: No, I'm not sure. Here, I actually revised my previous question with better language and added new information, So that answerers can help me better. Thanks anyway.

Comment: @DavoodKazemi stop reposting the same question

Comment: Sorry for being a bother. It wasn't intentional.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you think a custom post type would not work here? Is there anything about custom post types that you think does not fit your preferred structure?

The way I would go about this would be to:

- Define a custom post type, e.g. Company.
- For each non-title and non-description field, store the data as a custom post meta.

You can use the brilliant [Advanced Custom Fields](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/) plugin to set up the custom fields quickly.

If the data entry is your concern, you could export the data into a CSV file and programmatically import the data or use a plugin to do this. [Here is a list of plugins that you can use](https://wordpress.org/support/article/importing-content/#xml-and-csv) from WordPress's support docs.

Comment: I recommend reposting this answer here https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/378143/how-to-make-a-list-of-companies-information-and-display-them-to-user-using-cus